MySQL Process is going to sleep always and make processlist full of process like 150/200 process
i have a project developed in laravel and MySQL. in this project lots of process has been created in MySQL while using software. like 150/200 process created. but not killed automatically just gone to sleep.
is there any solution?
we are manually reset server and reset mysql server to solve, and trying some way but not works
